# How do you create an Observable AND store values from that Observable into a different Observable at the same time?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I have 2 Observables:

```
  country$!: Observable<Country>
  countryBorders$!: Observable<Country[]>
```

Im trying to retrieve the "country$" data from a HTTP GET request to here (in this example the country is USA):

https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/usa

and after I retrieve the particular countries data, I'd like to store the "borders" property array from that data into the "countryBorders$" observable.

---

Right now I am doing it like this:

```
  getCountriesByCodes(codes: string[]) {
   return this.http.get<Country[]>(
  `${this.api}alpha?codes=${codes.join(',')}`
);
}

 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params) => {
      let countryName = params['country'];
      this.country$ = this.apiService.getCountryByName(countryName).pipe(map(([info])=>{
        this.countryBorders$ = this.apiService.getCountriesByCodes(info.borders);
        return info;
      }))
    });
    };
```

but I've been told you shouldn't create or store Observable values in the subscribe function of another Observable.

---

What am I supposed to use here instead? mergeMap? switchMap? concatMap? Do I just replace "map" with one of those? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed nesting observables isn't recommended. You can simply update with `mergeMap`:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.activatedRoute.params.pipe(
    mergeMap((params) => {
      let countryName = params['country'];
      return this.apiService.getCountryByName(countryName).pipe(
        tap(([info]) => {
          this.countryBorders$ = this.apiService.getCountriesByCodes(info.borders);
        })
      );
    })
  ).subscribe(([info]) => {
    this.country$ = of(info);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> but I've been told you shouldn't create or store Observable values in
> the subscribe function of another Observable.

You should not have nested subscriptions. If you have one, that means whenever the first `Observable` emits a value, you create a new subscription to the second `Observable`.

You can do something like this:

```js
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params) => {
  let countryName = params['country'];
  this.country$ = this.apiService.getCountryByName(countryName);
  this.countryBorders$ = this.country$.pipe(map(([info]) => 
    this.apiService.getCountriesByCodes(info.borders)))
  });
};
```

Comment: When you use pipe(), is that subscribing to the observable? Because technically in my code there's only one "subscribe()".

Comment: No, using `pipe` only lets you pass `operators` to transform the data that this Observable emits. A subscription is only created when you call the `subscribe` method or use the `async` pipe in the template

Comment: so my original code is OK? I'm not using nested subscriptions?

Comment: Yes, it is fine - you are not calling `subscribe` on any `Observable`

Comment: How come all the other responses are telling me my code is bad practice then? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

With observables, you don't really "store to another observable", but rather declare an observable to start from another observable.  In your case `countryBorders$` would be defined from `country$`. So, you *could* do something like this:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
        let countryName = params['country'];
        this.country$ = this.apiService.getCountryByName(countryName);
        this.countryBorders$ = this.country$.pipe(
            switchMap(([info]) => this.apiService.getCountriesByCodes(info.borders))
        );
    });
}
```

Notice how `countryBorders$` is defined to start with the emissions from `country$`, then pipes the emission to a call to `getCountriesByCodes()`.  `switchMap` is used to "flatten the observable", meaning that instead of using plain `map`, which would emit type `Observable<T>`. `switchMap` will subscribe to the "inner observable" and emit its emissions, so you get an emission of type `T`.

---

The above code will work, but we can simplify this even more in a way that doesn't require `ngOnInit` nor need to explicitly call `.subscribe()`.

Let's first start by defining the `countryName` as an observable:

```js
private countryName$ = this.activatedRoute.params.pipe(params => params['country']);
```

Now, we can define `country$` to start with this observable:

```js
private country$ = this.countryName$.pipe(
    switchMap(countryName => this.apiService.getCountryByName(countryName))
);
```

And finally `countryBorders$`:

```js
public countryBorders$ = this.country$.pipe(
    switchMap(([info]) => this.apiService.getCountriesByCodes(info.borders))
);
```

Now you have an observable (`countryBorders$`) that will emit exactly the border data that you want.  You can cleanly consume this observable in your template using the `async` pipe:

```html
<div *ngIf="countryBorders$ | async as borders">
  <!-- use `borders` here -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here you can try this logic to merge two observables :**

```js
import { map, merge, Observable, tap } from 'rxjs';

const observable$ = new Observable((subscriber) => {
  subscriber.next(1);
  subscriber.next(2);
  subscriber.next(3);

  setTimeout(() => {
    subscriber.next(4);
  }, 4000);
});

const observable2$ = new Observable((subscriber) => {});

// here we merge two observables
let final$ = merge(observable$, observable2$);

final$.subscribe({
  next(x) {
    console.log(x);
  },
});
```